# Docker NodeJS connecting to mongo gives error "db.collection is not a function'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I've got a MongoDb server running in a Docker container. Everything seems to work fine.

I have another container which is running library/node and I want to connect to the MongoDb database.

I've followed http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/quick-start/quick-start/
Inside that second container I've run

```
npm init 
npm install mongodb --save
```

I'm then running the following js file:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://10.0.2.15:27017/mydb';
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
console.log("Connected successfully to server");
var collection = db.collection('documents');   
db.close();
});
```

I can connect to the mongo container but trying to get collections fails with an error:

```
 TypeError: db.collection is not a function
    at /app/app.js:5:21
    at args.push (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:431:72)
    at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:254:5
    at connectCallback (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:933:5)
    at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:794:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

What's going wrong here? Without the collection line the code works fine, suggesting a good connection to the db.

Comment: Following the example I did use "assert.equal(null, err);"
It works fine, it produces an error if the mongodb is offline, otherwise it goes through ok - I get "Connected successfully" line and then the error I quote.

Comment: It does seem to be a mongo error. Changing the mongodb dependancy version to 2.2.33 seemed to fix the issue.